# How to take a screenshot of a page N seconds after page is loaded with Chrome Headless?

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot

I want to make a screenshot of a page with Chrome Headless, and we've seen both the `--screenshot` and the `--virtual-time-budget` switches for taking a screenshot and limiting the browser's waiting for load time.

I have elements on the page however that wait for DOMContentLoaded to render, and we want to capture those too.

I'm looking for a way to take a screenshot, say, 5 seconds *after* the page is loaded, instead of right when it's considered loaded.

We're calling Chrome Headless from our NodeJS application like so:

```
cp.spawnSync("google-chrome-beta", ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--screenshot", "--profile-directory=Default", "--window-size=1920,6200", "--virtual-time-budget=25000", url]);
```

We know that there are possible npm libraries that can achieve this using an API from node, instead of using command line switches, but we're concerned about stability (the Chrome team likes to break all their internal APIs regularly).

### TL;DR

Is there anyway to make Chrome Headless wait a few seconds after page load before taking a screenshot?

Comment: David Schnurr shared nodejs script that does what you want [here](https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a). Run `nodejs index.js --url="http://www.eff.org" --delay=5000` for 5 second delay.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for the same thing. What I found is google puppeteer. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

There are lots of examples, but basically you can do what I did.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 5960, height: 4209})
    await page.goto('http://stackoverflow.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
    await timeout(10000)
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    browser.close();

})();
```

Comment: Mar 2019: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERROR: "networkidle" option is no longer supported. Use "networkidle2" instead`

Answer (score 3):

As [Vlastimil Ovčáčík](https://superuser.com/users/238468/vlastimil-ov%C4%8D%C3%A1%C4%8D%C3%ADk) states, David Schnurr has written and shared a nodeJS script for this exact purpose over on [Medium](https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a).

The script should be plug and play, minus some dependencies.

Setup is as such:

1. Clone the Git respository.
   `git clone https://github.com/schnerd/chrome-headless-screenshots.git`
2. Install dependencies:
   `npm install chrome-remote-interface minimist`
3. Run the script
   `node index.js --url="https://superuser.com/questions/1209741/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-page-n-seconds-after-page-is-loaded-with-chrome-he" --delay=4000`

Comment: Missing dependency `npm install mz` and then it errors about not being able to find chrome's debugger connection iirc. Both running the `index.js` as suggested here and the repository-included `run.sh` do not work with these instructions on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this page: Chrome has a new feature, doing just this. There's a new command line parameter `--timeout`.

```
chrome --headless=new --screenshot --timeout=5000 https://www.google.com
```

… and `chromium` for linux, of course.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/

Comment: Timeout is a maximum waiting time afaict, not a minimum. It seems that one needs to use Puppeteer nowadays